# how can i solve this error in jtable?

Tags: swing, netbeans, jtable

I want to display the data from database in table.I am getting this error "non-static variable jtable1 cannot be referenced from a static context". Help me with solving this error

```
st.executeQuery("select * from course" );
                 ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
                 ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                 int c_count = md.getColumnCount();
                 Vector data = new Vector(c_count);
                 Vector row = new Vector(c_count);
                 Vector colname = new Vector(c_count);
                 for(int i=0;i<c_count;i++)
                 {
                     colname.addElement(md.getColumnName(i));
                 }
                 while(rs.next())
                 {
                 for(int i=0;i<c_count;i++)
                 {
                   row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));  
                 }
                 data.addElement(row);
                 row = new Vector(c_count);
                 }
                 DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,colname);
                 jTable1.setModel(model);
```

Comment: it would be great if you could share with all a signature of the method that contains this code snippet as well as the jTable1 declaration

Comment: private javax.swing.JTable jTable1; is the declareation and the method is public static void main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main method has a static context, thus it has no access to any instances variables directly. Let's assume you have a class named Foo with the static main method and a private variable jTable1. First of all you should have to add a getter for the jTable1 variable with the following signature

```
public JTable getTable() {
 return jTable1;
}
```

Next, in your main method you have to create an instance of the Foo

```
Foo fooInstance = new Foo();
```

Now, you can set the model as shown below:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,colname);
fooInstance.getTable().setModel(model);
```

Finally, the Foo class will look like

```
public class Foo {


     private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;

     public JTable getTable() {
          return jTable1;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          //your code

          Foo fooInstance = new Foo();

          DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,colname);
          fooInstance.getTable().setModel(model);

           //your code
     }
}
```

In general, this topic is a something that you have to be familiar with, so take a look at the official Java tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ or just google it

Comment: thanks.!i have another doubt.why is vector class shown as obsolete collection.is it okay to run my program as such or should i modify it?

Comment: i had this doubt because i altered the code as u said and my error was cleared.when i run the file i get only an empty table with four rows and five columns.however i have created the same number of rows and columns in my database.why is it empty? @Cyril Deba

Comment: it is hard to say based  on the provided information. I would recommend debug the project and it could help resolve the problem